# Manipulating material of 3d object via API in three.js

Tags: javascript, json, api, three.js

I'm trying to dynamically update materials in my 3d object using an API call which is made every 2 seconds.

I have mapped my all my 3d nodes (just over 1k of them) and I would like to update them via feed of data. I have those nodes returned from my API formatted as JSON:

```js
{
  "SWITCHIP": "172.20.1.50",
  "ROW_ID": -2,
  "SIDE": "North",
  "ORIENTATION": "West",
  "BANK": 1,
  "PI": 7,
  "IP": "172.20.1.50",
  "NODE_NAME": "Body1.026",
  "NODE_NAME_GLTF": "Body1026",
  "COLORINDEX": 4,
  "COLORSTRING": "brown",
  "RGB": "(R=1.000000,G=0.073385,B=0.203163,A=1.000000)"
}
```

In my aframe/three.js scene I have imported my 3d model gltf and gave it `id="3dmodel"`. I have created a code to manipulate the material of one node within the 3d model like this

```js
AFRAME.registerComponent('modify-materials', {
  init: function() {
    let el = this.el;
    el.addEventListener("model-loaded", e => {
      var testarray = [];
      el.object3D.traverse(function(child) {
        console.log(child.name);
        testarray.push(child.name);
        if (child.name == "Body1481") {
          child.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
            color: '#ffffff',
            specular: '#ffffff',
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
});
```

I want to fetch the data from my API

```
   fetch("https://g2f4dc3e5463897-ardata.adb.uk-london-1.oraclecloudapps.com/ords/picluster/AR/DigitalTwin")
   .then((response) => {
     if (response.ok) {
       return response.json();
     } else {
       throw new Error("NETWORK RESPONSE ERROR");
     }
   })
   .then(data => {
     console.log(data);
   })
   .catch((error) => console.error("FETCH ERROR:", error));
```

and make the `child.name` dynamically read from the API i.e. `"NODE_NAME_GLTF":"Body1026"` and `color: '#ffffff'` changed to the

```
"COLORSTRING": "brown",
"RGB": "(R=1.000000,G=0.073385,B=0.203163,A=1.000000)"
```

hope that makes sense

Comment: 1. What does your map look like? Do you have a map of names to Meshes or Materials? That is what I would recommend. 2. You don't need to create an all new material unless you're changing its type (i.e. `MeshBasicMaterial` to `MeshPhongMaterial`). Just set your new values like `child.material.color.set( r. g. b )` then set `child.material.needsUpdate = true`.

Comment: yeah I have 1:1 mapping . What about the loop that we need to run through 1000 records?

Comment: If your input (stream data) contains the node name and new color, then you should be able to use your name:node map to update that node's material. In other words, don't loop through all your nodes checking if they have an update, loop through your stream data and use your map to access only nodes that need updated.

Comment: I dont think I understand. Dont I need to fetch the API somehow and then make it read from it. what you understand by map?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the use-case/workflow. It might be beneficial to your question if you could add runnable example code that presents a similar scene (with maybe 5 meshes rather than 1000) and reacts to similar data.

Comment: i modified post and added api call tha i need to modify to run through the nodes